# Clustering With K-Means in Python

Tags: python

I have the code but i am trying to find a method to plot the results

```
import numpy as np
import random


def cluster_points(X, mu):
    clusters = {}
    for x in X:
        bestmukey = min([(i[0], np.linalg.norm(x - mu[i[0]])) \
                         for i in enumerate(mu)], key=lambda t: t[1])[0]
        try:
            clusters[bestmukey].append(x)
        except KeyError:
            clusters[bestmukey] = [x]
    return clusters


def reevaluate_centers(mu, clusters):
    newmu = []
    keys = sorted(clusters.keys())
    for k in keys:
        newmu.append(np.mean(clusters[k], axis=0))
    return newmu


#def has_converged(mu, oldmu):


def find_centers(x, k):
    # Initialize to K random centers
    oldmu = random.sample(x, k)
    mu = random.sample(x, k)
    while not (set([tuple(a) for a in mu]) == set([tuple(a) for a in oldmu])):
        oldmu = mu
        # Assign all points in X to clusters
        clusters = cluster_points(x, mu)
        # Reevaluate centers
        mu = reevaluate_centers(oldmu, clusters)
    return (mu, clusters)

def init_board(N):
    X = np.array([(random.uniform(-1, 1), random.uniform(-1, 1)) for i in range(N)])
    return X

def init_board_gauss(N, k):
    n = float(N)/k
    X = []
    for i in range(k):
        c = (random.uniform(-1, 1), random.uniform(-1, 1))
        s = random.uniform(0.05,0.5)
        x = []
        while len(x) < n:
            a, b = np.array([np.random.normal(c[0], s), np.random.normal(c[1], s)])
            # Continue drawing points from the distribution in the range [-1,1]
            if abs(a) < 1 and abs(b) < 1:
                x.append([a,b])
        X.extend(x)
    X = np.array(X)[:N]
    return X
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Most of the code seems irrelevant to the question of how to plot something. What sort of data do you want to plot and what sort of plot do you want (most things can be plotted in multiple ways)?

Comment: https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/clustering-with-k-means-in-python/  i want to plot everything that appears in this url...i run the code but i want to see the results

Comment: Those are probably just scatter plots generated using [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/). If you read through the tutorial you should be able to rapidly generate such plots.

Comment: If you look at the [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) there are numerous examples of scatter plots, which when you click on them show you the code used to generate them. One of those demos can probably be tweaked to get what you want.